# convert hex code (in packet) to UTF-8

Tags: c, linux, utf-8, packet, smb

sturct ptr info

```
struct ptr {                  // packet struct
unsigned long srcip;
unsigned long dstip;
unsigned short srcport;
unsigned short dstport;
unsigned char *str;       // payload data of packet
unsigned short len;       // payload length
unsigned long ts;
};
```

find file path and save module code

```
char *msg = NULL;             // to save file path
int j = 0;
/* find file path and save */
for (i=84; i < ptr->len; i++) {
    if (ptr->str[i] > 0x00 && ptr->str[i] < 0x7f) {
        msg[j] = ptr->str[i];
        j++;
    }
    if (ptr->str[i] > 0x7f) {
        msg[j] = 0x23;
        j++;
    }
}
```

This is file path in SMB packet, i captured on Wireshark.

```
0000   5c 00 e0 ac c8 b2 5c 00 73 00 65 00 63 00 72 00  \.....\.s.e.c.r.
0010   65 00 74 00 5c 00 78 c7 ac c0 2e 00 74 00 78 00  e.t.\.x.....t.x.
0020   74 00 00 00                                      t...
```

current result =

```
msg : \####\secret\x###.txt
```

I just put '#' (0x23) temporarily..

and this is what i want =

```
msg : \고니\secret\인사.txt
```

I just found "e0 ac" are part of letter '고' , "c8 b2" are part of letter '니'

But i don't know how to convert..

In sum, i want convert hex code (in packet) to UTF-8.

Comment: _"e0 ac" are part of letter '고'_ could you clarify this sentence?

Comment: https://team-memories.com/tools/unicode
in this site "0xe0 0xac" convert to  '고'

Comment: @LPs I mean  '고' convert " \uACE0 " 

so i think "e0 ac" is letter  '고'

Comment: On nix system you can take a look at [iconv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html)

Comment: If you don't know the source encoding, it's very difficult to figure out what needs to be done.